# Search row with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the table

```
    *City       Crime*
    Bangkok    High
    Hongkong   Very High
    Seoul      Low, Average
    Texas      Average, High
    Jakarta    Low
    Singapore  Very Low
    Las Vegas  Average, Low
```

how's the sql to search where the crime "Low" 
i use the preg_split but i don't know to match the database

Comment: Try this.      select * from table where `crime` like '%Low%' and `crime` not like '%Very Low%';

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LIKE` matcher to select for a partial match on a string:

```
SELECT *
FROM cities
WHERE crime LIKE '%Low%'
```

If you need case insensitivity, use `LOWER(crime)` to convert the column to lowercase.

Comment: This query also returns data in which column value has 'Very Low'. The OP needs only the data which has 'Low'

Comment: Ah, wasn't sure based on the question, a simple AND conjunction should suffice in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

Mysql:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    City
WHERE `Crime` REGEXP '^Low' or `Crime` REGEXP ', Low' 
or `Crime` REGEXP 'Low,'
```

Sql:

```
select * from City
where (Crime like 'low%' or Crime like '%, low%' or Crime like '%low,%')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table 
where 
    `crime` like '%Low%' 
    and `crime` not like '%Very Low%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You select records **where** some criteria is met with `WHERE`.

```
select * from mytable where crime = 'Low';
```

There are further entries in your table where the crime string contains a 'Low' substring. E.g. 'Low, Average' and 'Average, Low'. I don't know the exact meaning of these, of course. Do both mean the same? Do they mean the crime is "low to avarage"? Or is it undecided whether "low or avarage"? And would you count this as "low" or would that be yet another level above "low"?

Then there is the entry 'Very Low'. Would you consider this "low" or a level beyond?

Depending on the answers you could extend above query to match all 'Low' substrings:

```
select * from mytable where crime like '%Low%';
```

Or use some more advanced string search, e.g.

```
select * from mytable
where ',' || replace(replace(crime, ', ', ','), ' ,', ',') || ',' like '%,Low,%';
```

which would get 'Low, Average' and 'Average, Low', but not 'Very Low'.